# Does anybody know why Lang-8 stopped accepting new membership?

Tags: language-exchange

I've heard a lot of good things about this language exchange site called [**Lang-8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lang-8.com). I was going to check it out for myself, but was rerouted to this thing called HiNative.  Later, I learned that Lang-8 stopped accepting new enrollment/subscriptions in March of this year.  Supposedly, enrollment has begun again, but it appears that new subscribers are still routed to HiNative.

Does anyone know why Lang-8 stopped accepting new membership and whether or not they plan to accept new members in the future?  Any information you can provide on this language exchange program, especially with regard to its status -- past, present, and future -- is appreciated, even if what you have is speculative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to the Lang-8 blog](http://blog.lang-8.com/post/164706442459/regarding-the-suspension-to-new-sign-ups-on-lang-8), they are 1) low on time and resources, and 2) having troubles with spammers/bots:

> There are a few reasons why we decided to implement this suspension, the main one being a lack of resources here at Lang-8, Inc. We’re an extremely small company, and we were having difficulty actively developing Lang-8 and its sister service HiNative simultaneously.
>
> ...
>
> We were also having an increasingly difficult time dealing with spammers and bots who were signing up for Lang-8 and abusing the platform. Again, we do not currently have the resources to implement preventative measures that are strong enough to combat this type of behavior, and we will be forced to extend the suspension period as a result.

As for when the suspension will be lifted, March 2018 appears to be a tentative date estimate:

> We had originally planned to lift the suspension after 6 months, but due to a continued lack of resources within the company, we will need to extend the period into next year.
>
> We are aiming to reopen sign-ups in March of 2018, though this date isn’t set in stone.

Comment: Thank you for tracking this down.  My experience with language blogs and the scant information I found regarding this issue in general made me think that I wouldn't find much with respect to this through the company's blogs.  You have proved me wrong.  I won't underestimate a company's blogs again!

Comment: The service is shutting down in Feb 2024.